# Troubleshooting SCSS: Why Aren't Absolute Imports Working?

Tags: typescript, next.js, sass

I have the following project structure

```
    - my-project
      - public
        - icons
          - nome.svg
      - src
        - components
          - MyComponent
            - MyComponent.module.scss
        - ...
      - ...
```

but when I try this:

```css
backgorund-image: url('public/icon/category-qualified.svg');
```

the following error occurs

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'public/icon/category-qualified.svg'
```

i add `baseUrl: './src'` in my tsconfig.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The baseUrl you are using starts from `src/`, so it cannot access `public` folder. You will have to go one level up with `"baseUrl": "."`.

Also, I would suggest to use the full power of these imports. You can add multiple paths to use as aliases:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["src/*"],
      "public/*": ["public/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: worked if i import in .tsx but not in scss

Comment: Finally work when i add `~public`

Comment: Sure, edit the answer accordingly to make it accurate